# 'list' object is not callable, Trying to access an item in a list and assign it to an object

Tags: python

I am running code that is serving to balance chemical equations for general chemistry. The file that I'm running from contains this code:

```
from equation import Equation
from time import sleep


def run_balance():
    # Runs the chemical equation balance algorithm
    print('=================================================')
    print('Insert chemical equation with elements in parentheses followed by the number of atoms:')
    print('Example: (H)2 + (O)2 = (H)2(O)1')
    user_input = str(input('>>> '))
    try:
        equation = Equation(user_input)
        print('Balanced equation: ' + equation.balance())
        sleep(3)
        run_balance()
    except IndexError:
        print('Invalid input...')
        sleep(3)
        run_balance()

run_balance()
```

The file where the `Equation` class is located contains the following code:

```
class Equation:
    # Create a class for chemical equations
    def __init__(self, equation):
        # Initialize equation into an object the code understands
        self.left = list()
        self.right = list()
        self.balanced = True

        integers = '0123456789'
        split = equation.split(' = ')
        left = split[0]
        right = split[1]
        left_components = left.split(' + ')
        right_components = right.split(' + ')
        total_left = dict()
        total_right = dict()
```

When I give any input, I receive the following error:

```
     14         integers = '0123456789'
     15         split = equation.split(' = ')
---> 16         left = split[0]
     17         right = split[1]
     18         left_components = left.split(' + ')

TypeError: 'list' object is not callable
```

I'm confused as I understand this error normally comes from using parentheses when trying to access an item in a list, for which you would just change the parentheses to square brackets. However, I am trying to assign `left` as the first half of `equation` after splitting it. Any advice?

Comment: What input are you giving? I tried with `'1 + 1 = 2'` and didn't get an error.

Comment: You can also unpack directly from splitting: a string's split method returns a list, which you know since you pick the 0'th and 1st elements of it, but you can write like this: `left, right = equation.split(' = ')`

Comment: AttributeError: 'Equation' object has no attribute 'balance'

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. See [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). We cannot effectively help you until you post your MRE code and accurately specify the problem. We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you specified.

Comment: I suspect that the code you’re running, and the Python source file you’re looking at, are not in sync.

Answer (score 0):

Your traceback doesn't make sense, probably for good reason.  Try to find that reason.

Sometimes the problem in this situation is that you have an old `.pyc` file lying around from a previous version of the code.  This can happen if e.g. you had an `equation` library, as well as a `equation.py` that got deleted at some point.